# Transferring a file from a server to another via SFTP using JAVA

Tags: java, server, ftp, sftp

Hello StackOverFlow Community,

I'm trying to figure out a way to Transfer some files from the server : 205.x.x.x with a usernamex/passwordx to another server 10.y.y.y with a usernamey/passwordy and then unzip them, cause basically they're zipped (.gz).

Can get some recommandations on what method should I follow ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: Up- and downloading via SFTP is possible by using [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), have a look at it...

Comment: This is a very complex question. You should at least ask the transfer and unzip parts separately.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Java Secure Channel](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). It works great. I am using it right now for a project.